# List of tables does not appear when a longtable style glossary is included in the document... I think?

Tags: table-of-contents, longtable, glossaries, grouping

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{report} 

%All packages included as I am not sure what the problem is.
\usepackage{tgbonum,dcolumn,graphicx,epsfig,caption,psfrag,lineno,amsmath,setspace,fancyhdr,afterpage,amssymb,subcaption,multirow,makecell,array,titlesec,datetime,times,amssymb,amsfonts,bm,color,soul,tikz,mathrsfs,longtable,etoolbox,xcolor,colortbl,hhline,verbatim}

\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Defect notation}
\makeglossaries
\glossarystyle{long}
\input{Glossaries/Glossaries}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} %Does appear when figures are included

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} %Does not appear in document at all and therefore is not in the Table of Contents

\glsaddall %No glossary terms appear in the document all are added here 
\begingroup\let\newpage\relax %To print all Glossaries one after another with no page break
\printglossary[title=Glossary of mathematical notation, toctitle=Glossary of mathematical notation]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long,title=Acronyms and abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=notation,style=long]
\endgroup

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{A table that does not appear in list of tables. \label{table}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Does & not & appear \\ \hline
in't & list & of tables \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you compiled twice? Btw: You should not use `\input` to insert glossary entries (`\loadglsentries` should be preferred).

Comment: Hello, thank you. I have changed the input method. And I compile (latex2ps), then makeglossaries, compile again, then again for good measure.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't supplied your `Glossaries/Glossaries.tex` file so I've used the test files provided with the `glossaries` package. Using those files shows the list of tables:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright,a4paper]{report} 

%All packages included as I am not sure what the problem is.
\usepackage{tgbonum,dcolumn,graphicx,epsfig,caption,psfrag,lineno,amsmath,setspace,fancyhdr,afterpage,amssymb,subcaption,multirow,makecell,array,titlesec,datetime,times,amssymb,amsfonts,bm,color,soul,tikz,mathrsfs,longtable,etoolbox,xcolor,colortbl,hhline,verbatim}

\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Defect notation}
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{long}
\loadglsentries[main]{example-glossaries-brief}
\loadglsentries[\acronymtype]{example-glossaries-acronym}
\loadglsentries[notation]{example-glossaries-symbols}

\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\glsaddall %No glossary terms appear in the document all are added here 
\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax %To print all Glossaries one after another with no page break
\printglossary[type=main,
 title=Glossary of mathematical notation,
 toctitle=Glossary of mathematical notation]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long,title=Acronyms and abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=notation,style=long]
\endgroup

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{A table that does not appear in list of tables. \label{table}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Does & not & appear \\ \hline
in't & list & of tables \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Example Image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Contents page:

[image: image of table of contents]

List of tables page:

[image: image of list of tables with first glossary starting beneath it]

There's no reason for the list of tables to not appear unless something has interrupted the build process, so check the transcript files for error messages. (The `.log` file for LaTeX errors, and the `.glg`, `.alg` and `.nlg` files for `makeindex` errors.)

---

A few notes unrelated to the problem:

Instead of using `\let\newpage\relax` it's better to change the glossary settings to use `\section*` instead of `\chapter*`:

```
\usepackage[toc,nonumberlist,acronym,section]{glossaries}
```

then just have

```
\printglossary[type=main,
 title=Glossary of mathematical notation,
 toctitle=Glossary of mathematical notation]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long,title=Acronyms and abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=notation,style=long]
```

or add an overall chapter to separate it from the table of contents:

```
\chapter*{Notation}
\printglossary[type=main,
 title=Glossary of mathematical notation,
 toctitle=Glossary of mathematical notation]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=long,title=Acronyms and abbreviations]
\printglossary[type=notation,style=long]
```

[`epsfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/epsfig) is deprecated and there's no point loading it when you've already loaded `graphicx`. Just use `\includegraphics` to include image files.

The [`times`](https://ctan.org/pkg/times) package is also obsolete and should be replaced with `math­ptmx`.